# Noflo custom components

Tags: javascript, node.js, noflo

I'm trying to build a working example using a custom component using noflo. Could somebody please explain how I should reference my component from within my .fbp file. The examples in the docs all seem to relate to npm based components.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have `components/ComponentName.coffee` (or .js), and this file is registered in `package.json` as

```
noflo: {
  components: {
      "ComponentName": "components/ComponentName.coffee"
  }
}
```

then you should be able to refer to it in a .fbp file as

```
'hello' -> IN node(ComponentName)
```

or

```
'hello' -> IN node(packagename/ComponentName)
```

where `packagename` is the project name set in package.json.

The declaration in the package.json can be automated using `grunt-noflo-manifest`.

It is the same for noflo-browser, just with `component.json` instead of `package.json`

Comment: This should really be explained in the documentation